# How to calculate pprof output and avoid pprof to drop nodes which their cum is less than 0.10s

Tags: go, pprof

I'm trying to figure out how pprof calculates the %cum of each node in my Go application output.
I've attached part of my pprof png output to emphesise the problem which I'm trying to figure out [pprof png output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zbh6.png)
In this part of the pprof output there are two nodes:

Node A) runtime scanobject -

> flat=1.06s %flat=5.54%
>
> cum=1.64s %cum=8.57%

Node B) runtime findobject (which is being called by scanobject)-

> flat=0.46s %flat=2.4%
>
> cum=0.54s %cum=2.82%

No metter how cumulative A is being calculated, the numbers does not sum up to func A cumulative (1.64s):

> A flat + B flat = 1.06s + 0.46s = 1.52s
>
> A flat + B cum = 1.06s + 0.54s = 1.6s

One thing that might explain this difference, is that pprof dropps cumulatives which are less than 0.10s, so it might be that there are minor functions which are related to node A that are missing from the pprof output.
If that is the root cause, I was wondering if there is a way to tell pprof to make full pprof output

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `--trim=false` to show all nodes in the report

https://github.com/google/pprof/blob/master/internal/driver/commands.go#L165

Comment: then you should accept the answer to give it better visibility to other users. Thanks!

Comment: Click on the V at the left of the response @torbido